# React + Express: Axios returns 405 Method Not Allowed on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, axios

I am working on an app with a React front-end and an Express API which are hosted on the same server.

It works fine in local but as soon as I deploy it to Heroku, each request from the front-end to the back-end returns `405: Method Not Allowed`. I have been looking for answers but most point to [using CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56538556/status-code-405-not-allowed-in-react-frontend-hosted-on-heroku) and I already do. I thus do not know if my problem comes from the build, from a misuse of axios or from a faulty express.js config.

I have also tried adding a react proxy URL but it does not solve the problem.

Directory stucture is as follows:

```
├── Express
|   └── server.js
├── React
|   └── App.js
├── buildScript.js
└── package.json
```

Here is my server.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const compression = require('compression')
const cors = require('cors')
const helmet = require('helmet')
const path = require('path');

// Import routes
const poisRouter = require('./routes/pois-route')
const autocompleteRouter = require('./routes/autocomplete-route')

// Set default port for express app
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4001

const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(helmet())
app.use(compression())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// Serve static files from the React App
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

// Implement Poi & Autocomplete routes
app.use('/pois', poisRouter)
app.use('/autocomplete', autocompleteRouter)

// Wildcard to send back to React
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});


// Start express app
app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log(`Server is running on: ${PORT}`)
})
```

Example request from the React front-end, which gives me a 405 error:

```js
  const fetchPoisFromAutocomplete = async () => {
    // Send GET request to 'autocomplete/fetch' endpoint

    axios
      .get('/autocomplete/fetch', {
        latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude
      })
      .then(response => {
        // Update the pois state
        console.dir(response.data)

      })
      .catch(error => console.error(`There was an error retrieving the poi list: ${error}`))
  }

fetchPoisFromAutocomplete();
```

Package.json scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node ./buildScript",
    "build-front": "react-scripts build",
    "start": "node app/server.js",
    "start-server": "nodemon app/server.js",
    "start-front": "react-scripts start",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run start-server\" \"npm run start-front\" --kill-others --kill-others-on-fail",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "heroku-postbuild": "react-scripts build"
  },
```

Build Script:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const fse = require('fs-extra')
const childProcess = require('child_process')

if (fs.existsSync('./build')) {
  fse.removeSync('./build')
}

childProcess.execSync('react-scripts build', { stdio: 'inherit' })

fse.moveSync('./build', './server/build', { overwrite: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the full url of the endpoint on heroku here:

```
.get('/autocomplete/fetch', {
```

i.e.

```
.get('https://your-heroku-app.herokuapp.com/autocomplete/fetch'
```

to see if that works. I suspect your react app is actually trying to call a different URL than where the API is hosted.

Comment: I had tried that earlier with no luck. I think the problem is somehow linked to my build.

Answer (score -1):

Here in Stack overflow, someone had this issue, see below one of the comments, not sure if it is the same issue.

> App is on heroku server. I have contacted support and they replied: "The create-react->app-buildpack uses the heroku/static buildpack which in turn uses a nginx web server. >Unfortunately nginx does not allow POST calls from static pages. You will need to make a >GET request here."

[I am getting 405 method not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50970961/how-to-enable-post-method-on-heroku-server-for-react-app-i-am-getting-405-met)

Not sure if that's your case, but ensure that you did not upload your Build folder to your repo as this will break it once you upload it to heroku.

Comment: Hi John, welcome to Stack Overflow! If you believe that someone else has already answered the question, it is most helpful to flag the question as a duplicate and let the moderators filter out the doubled questions.

Comment: I am not sure this is the same case, as I am able to do the POST without issues, 
My issues were to have deployed the Build folder to my repo and uploaded it to Heroku, once I moved it, my app works. 
Was just sharing as I am not sure if Marwann has the same problem or not.